# Why is the pageviews of the session entryl url higher than the pageviews of the page url with the same url?

Tags: analytics

I am comparing page views for the following conditions :

1. dimension : session entry - filter : session entry url = url
2. dimension : page url - filter : page url = url (same as above)

page views of the first condition is higher than that of condition 2, i thought that the second one would be higher as thare can be entries from somewhere else for that page url ?
I am not sure which one is should use

Thanks !

Comment: Is this in Google Analytics 4?

Comment: On the assumption that it is GA4; is thresholding being applied to one of the report? Are you sure no other filters or comparison segments are in place? Are you sure you're looking at identical time periods (GA4 has a tendency for resetting the time window you're viewing).